# Log SOAP Envelop in message flow of Proxy in OSB

Tags: soap, proxy, osb, envelope

Is there a way to see te entire SOAP Envelop while developing a proxy message flow on OSB? I was thinking about using a Log action, but envelope is not a context variable. Is there a way to build it? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that SOAP envelope is not a context variable when a SOAP message reaches Proxy.

You can rebuild the SOAP Envelope using following expression but change the namespace according to SOAP version. Assign it to a variable and log it after

**For v1.2**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
 <env:Header>
    {$header/*}
 </env:Header>
 <env:Body>
    {if ($fault) then ($fault) else ($body/*)}
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```